# Matlab interp signal length

Tags: matlab, interpolation, sampling

Consider the simple Matlab script

```
t = linspace(0, 1, 11);
y = t.^2;
y_up = interp(y, 2);
```

The sampling frequency for `y` is 10 Hz (assuming `t` is in seconds). The length of `y_up` is 22. That does not make the sampling frequency of `y` 20 Hz but rather 21 Hz.

The doc of `interp` states

> Y = interp(X,R) resamples the sequence in vector X at R times
> the original sample rate.

An easy but ugly fix is

```
t = linspace(0, 1, 11);
y = t.^2;
y_up = [y(1), interp(y(2:end), 2)];
```

Is the doc wrong or I haven't understood something?

Comment: You misunderstood something: the end point should not be included in sampling a signal, the end point is the same as the starting point (as Hz only make sense for signals assumed to be periodic, it's a measure of frequencies) . t=linspace(0,1-1/11,11) is the appropriate t for your calculations of frequencies. Your solution is also wrong as its y values are not uniformly sampled in t